# Loader.io simulating Sinatra session variables

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, load-testing

I want to run load tests on my server using Loader.io. I am using Sinatra's default session through `:enable session` and log in a user through the following method:

```
# verify a user name and password
post '/nanotwitter/v1.0/users/session' do
  user = UserService.get_by_username_and_password({ :username => params[:username], :password => params[:password] })
  if user
    session[:user] = user[:id]
  else
    session[:login_error] = { :error_codes => ['l-inv'], :message => 'Account credentials are invalid.' }
  end
  redirect to '/'
end
```

I am not worried about encryption of the user's credentials - this is for a school project. In the code above, once a user is authenticated, their id is stored in a 'user' variable in the session.

I load the root page by checking if the user is logged in. If there is a session variable named user present, I load a "logged in" root page instead of the default root page. That is a simple `if session[:user]` check.

I want to simulate a logged in user for a 'maintain client load' test on Loader.io. Does anyone know how I would construct the request body to simulate that this session variable exists?

Comment: "I am not worried about encryption of the user's credentials - this is because of ____" is a justification used at every level of development, and I'd suggest you get rid of bad habits in your thought process like that as soon as possible, lest you end up like the other sloppy developers out there that write security holes in their apps, [especially when it's this easy to add encryption](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/encrypted_cookie/0.0.4)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to create a `before` block that creates the logged in user. Put a [condition on it so it only runs in development mode](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters), or only have it in a branch that will never reach production… just don't let it into production code!